# Arimo font doesn't seem to work anywhere

Tags: css, google-chrome, ubuntu, fonts, font-face

I'm trying to use a font called [Arimo](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Arimo) on my blog and I can't seem to get it to work no matter what I try.  I've tried using it via Google Fonts and by downloading it and serving it with my blog using [this helper app](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts/arimo?subsets=latin,latin-ext).

I'm using Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04.  Other fonts will work, but whenever I try to use Arimo, it defaults back to Liberation Sans.  There are no errors in the console or files that error in the network tab of dev tools.  In fact, the font never even appears to attempt to download.

Here's the smallest repeatable sample.

```
/* CSS */
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo';

body {
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
}
```

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div>Here's some sample text.</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2qur7ack/

I have no idea what else to do to try to fix it.

Comment: I just tried replacing the Arimo font with Roboto and that works just fine.  What is it about the Arimo font that doesn't seem to want to work with  Chrome on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

This is working correctly for me, on your jsfiddle.

Note that Arimo is designed to look like Arial, so you may not immediately be able to tell the difference, especially given your fallback font is "sans-serif" which will default to Arial on Windows machines.

Try using a fallback of "serif" or "monospace" to better verify if it's working.

If it's not working, it could be due to a conflict with a font installed on your computer.  If you have a font with the name "Arimo" installed on your computer then the browser may attempt to use that font instead of the webfont.  If there is a problem with the font installed on your computer this could cause it to fail for you.

So, another troubleshooting step would be to try it on another computer.

Comment: What browser and OS are you using?  I just tried a different computer with Ubuntu 16.04 and Chrome and the same issue occurred.  There are no fonts named Arimo installed on either computer and I know it's using Liberation Sans because when I inspect it using dev tools and go to the computed tab, it says Liberation Sans under rendered fonts.  Also, I did try not specifying sans-serif and specifying serif instead, and it used Liberation Sans in both cases.

Comment: Chrome on Windows 7.  Dev tab says Arimo - Network resource under rendered fonts.  It sounds like Ubuntu is using Liberation Sans as an Arimo substitute, though I have no idea why.

Comment: You could ask on askubuntu.com?

Comment: I may do that.  It's either a Linux thing or a Chrome on Linux thing or something having to do with that font.  It seems to be the only one that doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Arimo and Liberation Sans are both designed to be metrically compatible with Arial so it would make sense for Ubuntu to set them up as replacements of each other - even though in this situation (Chrome preferring a replacement font that's installed over the correct font online) it is not working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me on Mac Chrome. Inspector shows it working. I even changed the fallback font to cursive and got the same results.

[image: modified with cursive]

Try setting the `local` font name to something that could never conflict with an installed font name, like the Unicode Smiley Face (☺︎). [Read Paul Irish's take on the issue](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/font-face-gotchas/#smiley).